# How to test different classes/structs implementing an interface using google test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to use typed test concept available in google test. The description of this concept matches what I intend to do, but I cannot figure it out completely. I want to test structs which implements an interface, since they are totally different once, they need to be initialized with different values/instances.

Simply my code is as follows

```
struct Serializable
{
    virtual sObj serialize() = 0;
    virtual void unserialize(sObj) = 0;
};

struct s1 : serializable
{
  int attrI1;
  int attrI2;
  sObj serialize()
  {
    //serialize an instance of this struct
  }
  void unserialize(sObj)
  {
    //unserialize data to instance of this struct
  }
}

struct s2 : serializable
{
  char attrC;
  void serialize()
  {
    //serialize an instance of this struct
  }
  sObj unserialize()
  {
    //unserialize data to instance of this struct
  }
}
```

And I want to test s1 and s2 with different instances/values. The test should look like:

```
template <typename T>
int testSerialzable(T& t)
{
  sObj obj = t.pack();

  T temp; 
  TEST_EQ(temp.unpack(obj), t); 
}
```

Can someone please tell me if this is possible to do and how?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. for the example that I had above. It will be like:

```
template<class T>
struct TestSerializable : public ::testing::Test
{
    static T serializedType;
};

TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestSerializable);

TYPED_TEST_P(TestSerializable, serializationTest)
{
  sObj obj = t.serialize();

  TypeParam temp; 
  ASSERT_EQ(temp.unserialize(obj), t); 
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestSerializable, serializationTest);


typedef ::testing::Types<s1, s2> MyTypes;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(MySerialiInstantiation, TestSerializable, MyTypes);


template<> s1 TestSerializable<s1>::serializedType(/*instance of s1 with proper values*/s1());
template<> s2 TestSerializable<s2>::serializedType(/*instance of s1 with proper values*/s2());
```

Answer (score 0):

The original sample can't be compiled, I post my successful change for reference. If you need the full source code, please refer to the link(https://github.com/dougpuob/googletest-sample/blob/master/source/test-derived-func-by-interface/main.cpp).

```
#include "BinarySearchLoop.h"
#include "BinarySearchRecursive.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

template <class T>
struct TestBinarySearch : public ::testing::Test {
  static T Instance;
};

TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestBinarySearch);

TYPED_TEST_P(TestBinarySearch, PositiveInteger) {
  std::vector<int> SortedArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  ASSERT_EQ(4, Instance.search(SortedArray, 5));
  ASSERT_EQ(5, Instance.search(SortedArray, 6));
  ASSERT_EQ(0, Instance.search(SortedArray, 1));
  ASSERT_EQ(8, Instance.search(SortedArray, 9));
}

TYPED_TEST_P(TestBinarySearch, NegativeInteger) {
  std::vector<int> SortedArray = {-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1};
  EXPECT_EQ(+6, Instance.search(SortedArray, -2));
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, +0));
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, -9));
}

TYPED_TEST_P(TestBinarySearch, Integer) {
  std::vector<int> SortedArray = {-1, 0, 3, 5, 9, 12};
  EXPECT_EQ(+4, Instance.search(SortedArray, 9));
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, 2));
}

TYPED_TEST_P(TestBinarySearch, SingleElement) {
  std::vector<int> SortedArray = {5};
  EXPECT_EQ(+0, Instance.search(SortedArray, 5));
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, 1));
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, 6));
}

TYPED_TEST_P(TestBinarySearch, TwoElementsOnly) {
  std::vector<int> SortedArray = {1, 5};
  EXPECT_EQ(+1, Instance.search(SortedArray, 5));
  EXPECT_EQ(+0, Instance.search(SortedArray, 1));
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, 2));  // Not in the array.
  EXPECT_EQ(-1, Instance.search(SortedArray, 7));  // Not in the array.
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(TestBinarySearch,
                           PositiveInteger,
                           NegativeInteger,
                           Integer,
                           SingleElement,
                           TwoElementsOnly);

typedef ::testing::Types<BinarySearchLoop, BinarySearchRecursive> MyTypes;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(MyBinarySearchInstantiation,
                              TestBinarySearch,
                              MyTypes);

template <>
BinarySearchLoop TestBinarySearch<BinarySearchLoop>::Instance;

template <>
BinarySearchRecursive TestBinarySearch<BinarySearchRecursive>::Instance;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  int Ret = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return Ret;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's more convenient to use [value-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#value-parameterized-tests) for testing different implementations of an interface. Google Test's [sample7](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/samples/sample7_unittest.cc) shows how to do that.

Comment: The types that are from different types. I need to create an temp instance of the type being test, so I cannot use value-parameterized tests.